# javascript float comparison gives unexpected result

Tags: javascript, floating-point, comparison

I would expect this comparison to skip throwing the error, and when I remove '=' it behaves the way I would expect.  Any idea why?

```
if (!0.03509624834492526 >= 0) {
    throw new Error("DOH");
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is that `!0.0350...` is converting the value into a boolean, and the result is false. Next, comparing false to 0 is true when using an equal sign, so that's true. See these alerts:

```js
alert('!0.03509624834492526 is "' + !0.03509624834492526 + '"')
alert('false >= 0 is "' + (false >= 0) + '"')
```

If you wanted to check whether the number is not larger then or equal to 0, well it leaves only one option, it's smaller. Try:

```
if (0.03509624834492526 < 0) {
    throw new Error("DOH");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer, had to make the order of comparisons explicit, see below:

```
if (!(0.03509624834492526 >= 0)) {
    throw new Error("DOH");
}
```

Comment: Instead of `!(x >= y)` use `x < y`.

Answer (score -3):

It may be because you are using 3 operators i.e (!,>,=)

You can use 2 operators in an expression

you can change your expression like

```
if((!0.03509624834492526 > 0)&&(!0.03509624834492526 = 0)){
--- 
}
```

hope this will work for you

Comment: _"Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment"_. This is not at all how JavaScript, or any other programming language for that matter, works.